# Show Progress Visually

Tags: c#, function, report, progress

I have a function that performs several steps, one at a time, and I would like to display a form or something that tells the user their function is being processed

Basically the function in the Main Form looks like this:

```
 public void MyFunction ()
{
//Step1, takes aproximately 20 seconds
//Step2, takes 10 seconds
//Step3, takes about 25 seconds
}
```

So, the idea is to inform the user something is under process, because during Step 1, 2 and 3, the GUI remains unresponsive. I don't want to use a simple ProgressBar, it's an image processing software and there's no space to add a ProgressBar, it should be something that pops up basically. I was thinking on another form but not sure how would that work..

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you,

Matias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a simple solution consider this:

Create a another form (in my case `Progress`) and put something on  it which visualizes the progress. In my case it looks like this:

[image: Progess form]

The form itself has the `FormBorderStyle` set to `FixedToolWindow` and `StartPosition` set to `CenterParent`.

Now change the constructor to the a `BackgroundWorker` argument and set up the events and start the process.

```
public Progress(BackgroundWorker task)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    task.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => Close();
    task.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => pB_progress.Value = args.ProgressPercentage;
    task.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

In the main form just add something like this:

```
private void PopupJob()
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker
    {
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = false,
        WorkerReportsProgress = true
    };
    worker.DoWork += OurRealJob;
    new Progress(worker).ShowDialog();
}

private void OurRealJob(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
{
    var wrk = (BackgroundWorker) sender;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    wrk.ReportProgress(30);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    wrk.ReportProgress(100);
}
```

To show the popup progress thingy simply call `PopupJob`. The `OurRealJob` can be replaced with your code.

When you do it this way, the code will run in the background and the form will stay responsive. Because we are calling `Form.ShowDialog()` the progress form will be at the front and the main form can not be used until the job is done.

Answer (score 0):

in C#.NET there is an object for a progress bar.  It has a property called step that is an int that increases the progress by that value.  You increase the progress by running the PerformStep() method. Which might look like this.

`progressBar1.PerformStep();`

You will have to figure out how you want to measure progress.
You can hide the object and use the value in a pop-up window.

Comment: Thanks, I could do that, but I'm more interested in how to display the pop-up window.. I can't just put a messagebox I believe.

Comment: Well, you could make your own form and load that. Put the bar on it, and tell the form to close when it fills up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WinForms, you will find a class matching your expectations there:
[SxProgress overview and source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829395/an-easy-to-use-progress-bar-for-winforms)

```
SxProgress.Execute("XXXXX in progress...",3,false,false,myFunction_ExecInThread,new object[]{})

    private bool myFunction_ExecInThread,_ExecInThread(int ItemIndex,object[] UserObjects)
    { // 3 steps ==> ItemIndex varies from 0 to 2
      switch (i)
        { 
           case 0 : // your step 1 code there
                    // if you have a n/count progress info in step 1 process, use this:
                    // SetSubProgressValue(n,count,UserObjects) 
                    break ;
           case 1 : // your step 2 code there
           case 2 : // your step  3 code there
        }
       return true ; // or false if a step fails
    }
```